# submit button doesn't work with html code

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modal</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modalUI.css">

    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#create-user').click(function(){
                $('#dialog').dialog("open");
            });

            $('#dialog').dialog({
                draggable: true, 
                resizable: false, 
                closeOnEscape: true,
                modal: true,  
                autoOpen: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>john@example.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mary</td>
                    <td>Moe</td>
                    <td>mary@example.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><br>

        <input type="button" value="Show Dialog" id="create-user"/>
        <div id="dialog" title="Create new User">
            <form id="form2" action="">
                <label for="name">FirstName</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="fname" ><br>

                <label for="lastname">LastName</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="lname" ><br>

                <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" ><br><br>

                <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitDemo">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My submit button doesn't work when the dialog popup. What should I write on my jQuery? 
p.s Submit works outside the div dialog. But how to make it work into the dialog??

Dont mind this lorem ipsum thing.
(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.)

Comment: Have you closed the brackets of $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: Why are you calling submit() function on submit button click? It should be called automatically.

Comment: It isn't working automatically

Comment: `dialog()` is not a standard method of the jQuery library - it's part of jQueryUI. Have you included that as well?

Comment: @m1crdy Yes I did it on my code. I forgot to do it here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I did. I will edit my whole code

Comment: based on the code you posted your form does not have a action, hence it does nothing.

Comment: @Vaidas `<button type="submit"`, which the OP's code already has will do exactly the same thing as your suggestion.

Comment: @Dejan.S With no action defined it should submit the data to the same page and reload.

Comment: Do you have any JS capturing the submit button not shown here?

Comment: You're including jQuery 3 times. You can remove the second two. You're also including jQueryUI twice, remove the first one (the non '.min.js'). There's also a mis-matched `form` tag which will be causing problems and needs to be removed.

Comment: There are two forms being stacked, this is likely the cause of the issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He's stacked two forms, I guess this is because of the Show Dialog button, which is an input. That should probably be a link with an onclick, not in a form, so there are not form stacking issues.

Comment: @MattCowley that is making the assumption that he has a post called that.

Comment: @MattCowley yep, you're right. I missed the closing tag as it wasn't clearly formatted. OP: nested forms are not valid HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and MattCowley first of all, I'm a she. And the second one, it didnt matter that I had included the jQuery UI twice. It was all about nested forms.

Comment: @Wavelet My bad, however you shouldn't include resources more than once, slows down a page load and sends more requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The submit button in your dialog is not working because you've got nested forms - `form2` is inside `form1`, which is not valid.

Move the dialog (`<div id="dialog"` and everything inside it) outside of `form1` and the submit button will cause a postback as expected.

P.S. Despite the title of the question, the root cause of this issue is nothing to do with jQuery, or even Javascript. It's simply malformed HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Also, how can I submit the data into the form1?

Comment: if you have done what I suggest, then you haven't got any data in form1 to submit. All the form fields are within your dialog, and enclosed within form2

Comment: Yes I did it, and worked perfectly. But now, The data that I will put into the form 2(into the dialog), I need them to be showed into the form1. Can I do it in anyway without using db?

Comment: yes you can use javascript/jQuery to just copy the contents of each form element into an element somewhere else on the page. You don't have to save it to the db at at all, unless you want the data to persist beyond the life of the page. BTW, you don't need a `<form>` if all you want to do is display data (e.g. form1 in your case) - forms in HTML are for data entry, not display.

Answer (score 0):

Form tag is missing instructions, namely...
method="post"
action=""

Answer (score -1):

If you can use inline Javascript, you could try using an `onclick` attribute.

This would be like:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Dialog" id="create-user" onclick='$("#dialog").dialog("open");' />
```

If you can use inline Javascript, try ditching jQuery with the event listener.

```
<input type="button" value="Show Dialog" id="create-user"/>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("create-user").addEventListener("click", function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog("open");
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT:
As others said, you could also change the input element to a button. That would look better, since the button is not in a form.

```
<button type="button" id="create-user">Show Dialogue</button>
```

Comment: Don't use inline JS code. Use unobtrusive event handlers. This is also logically no different to what the OP already has.